# how can i override the Dialog Style of a theme like appcombat?

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes

i have been trying to make my own dialog style. This is what i have now:

[image]

There are two issues I want to fix, I want to get rid of the blue line below the title.
And I have applied a listSelector to the list which is probably been overridden by the parent style, because it only appears on the selected item.

This is the code of the style of the dialog:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector</item>
</style>
```

I have tried changing the parent and using Theme.Dialog. The problem then becomes that i do not want borders around the dialog. And by setting the windowBackground to transparent did not fix that.
People said I would have to create my own 9png, and I did but somehow it was added on top of the Theme.Dialog style.

How should I proceed given my problem?
It seems that my style does not override the parent's attributes given, only adds to them?

Here is the listSelector code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_selected="false"
 android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

Another way I could deal with this would be to change the blue line below the title color. Is that possible?